# iOS Facebook Access Token not caching

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a custom button that I use for Facebook login, and it was working fine until recently. The access token was cached and the next time the user launched the app, the continue button was displayed in its place.

Recently however the marked line returns nil regardless of whether the user has previously logged in. I'm at a loss as to why - I haven't made any code changes in this part of the app?

Occasionally the login will fail with the following error also:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.login Code=308 "(null)"
```

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil){  // <<<< ALWAYS RETURNS NIL
        self.continueButton.hidden = true
    } else {
        self.loginButton.hidden = true
        self.notYouButton.hidden = false
    }
}

@IBAction func loginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let permissions = ["user_about_me","user_relationships","user_birthday","user_location","user_status","user_posts", "user_photos"]
    let login = FBSDKLoginManager()
    login.logInWithReadPermissions(permissions, handler: {
        (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult result, NSError error) -> Void in
        if(error == nil){
        self.loginButton.hidden = true
        self.continueButton.hidden = false
        self.notYouButton.hidden = false
        self.notYouButton.enabled = false
        //self.performSelector("showBrowse", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 1.0)
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```

EDIT: On further testing it seems that calling FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() is returning nil if called in viewDidLoad(), but if I call it from a button press it returns the Facebook token as expected.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {
        print (token)
    } else {
        print ("no token")                        <<<<< RETURNS
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {
        print (token)                             <<<<< RETURNS
    } else {
        print ("no token")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a problem in my appDelegate where I was setting up a custom View Controller. I reverted the code to use storyboards and the issue was resolved - not a resolution per se for anyone with similar issues but it's enough for me to get on.